# Setting Tab Stops with \hfill

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, tabbing

My starting point is the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Section Number: \hfill A01: 8:00--8:50 am \hfill A02: 9:00--9:50 am \hspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{document}
```

This produces spacing that I like, but I need another line, which I would like to align against the first line. I thought of putting it in a `tabbing` environment like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
Section Number:\hfill\=A01: 8:00--8:50 am\hfill\=A02: 9:00--9:50 am \hspace*{\stretch{1}}\\
                     \>A03: 10:00--10:50 am    \>A04: 11:00--11:50 am
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

But the `tabbing` environment suppresses the `\hfill` commands. I know that I can set the spacing explicitly with `\hspace` commands, but is there a way to set tab stops against stretchy spaces?

Comment: Isn’t the `tabular*` environment what you are looking for?

Comment: @GuM Hmm, I wasn't familiar with `tabular*`. The code `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}` gets me pretty close, except that I've lost the space to the right of the last column. How can I get that back?

Comment: Well, can’t you simply add one extra column you never use, _e.g._, `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llll}`? (:-)

Comment: @GuM Figured that out as you were typing! If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Let’s do the other way round: you answer your own question, and I’ll upvote… :-)  **Edit:** Note that it is better to say `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}...` than `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}...`

Comment: @GuM What's the difference between `\textwidth` and `\linewidth`?

Comment: `\textwidth` refers to the full width of the text area, and this might not be what you want: the most obvious example of when this happens is two-column mode, but there are other cases.  `\linewidth` always refers to the width currently used in paragraph justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get what I want with the `tabular*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llll@{}}
Section Number: & A01: 8:00--8:50 am   & A02: 9:00--9:50 am \\
                & A03: 10:00--10:50 am & A04: 11:00--11:50 am
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\linewidth` forces the table to fill the width of the line, `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` adds the stretchy space between the columns, and the extra column `l` gives me my space to the right of the last column.
Also note the `@{}` after the last (unused) column, which suppresses the small, but unwanted space at the far right.

Comment: I took the liberty to slightly refine your answer.

Comment: The `&`s at the end of each line aren’t necessary either.